# React passing value from child to another parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, single-page-application

I have a problem passing value from component named `Item` to component `NavBar`. The tree looks like this.

[image: tree]

In `Item` component I have button, that is calling function `handleAddToCart`

```
<button onClick={this.handleAddToCart} style={btnStyle} className="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">ADD TO CART</button>


handleAddToCart = () => {
    console.log(this.state.price, this);
    this.props.changeValue(this.state.price)
};
```

And in `NavBar` component I have a function that is supposed to receive price of item

```
changeValue = (totalPrice) => {
    this.setState({
        totalPrice: totalPrice
    });
};
```

And then display it

```
{this.state.totalPrice.toFixed(2)}
```

the problem is that in `Item` component function called `changeValue` is unrecognized. Is it even possible to pass values straight to another child without passing it step by step to parent=>another parent=>child ? How should it be done correctly?

Comment: 1 more way of doing this, is by using Redux, then you won't need to pass through parent

Comment: probably not implemented properly, I usually think of it as a tree since I don't use Redux yet, a shared state should be at the top of the tree. so the parent of both parents should have the state. updating that single state should update it everywhere.

Comment: Take a look at this https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html if you don't want to use Redux or create a shared state in some parent component.

Comment: Which property is passed from parent to child component ?! you should have passed it as a prop. I can't see that. Explain please.

Comment: I ended up passing value from App to NavBar, which is by default 0, but now im stuck on passing price from Item component and updating it in App component. Im trying to call function that is in App component from Item component to update it, but it dosn't see declared parent's function.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.
Button in item component:

```
onClick={() => this.props.handler(this.state.price)}
```

Passing values to item in itemsList

```
{this.props.items.map(item => <Item
                key={item.id}
                price={item.price}
                img={item.img}
                imgDesc={item.imgDesc}
                itemDesc={item.itemDesc}
                handler={this.props.handlePriceChange}
            />)}
```

In App component function:

```
handlePriceChange = (priceValue) => {
    this.setState({totalPrice: this.state.totalPrice + priceValue});
    this.setState({totalItems: this.state.totalItems + 1});
};
```

and passing function to child (itemsList)

```
<ItemsList items={this.state.items} handlePriceChange={this.handlePriceChange}/>
```

Finally in navBar:

```
Items: {this.props.totalItems}
Sum: {this.props.totalPrice.toFixed(2)}
```